# Cakephp: Login of different users with a different platform in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Hie guys, i have an application where authentication is working pretty well.
I used the tutorial in cookbook http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/corelibraries/components/authentication.html 
The users table is linked to the groups table.
All the users in my users table perform different roles basing on the groups they belong to and they use the same view for log in.
I need to add another user called buyer who is not in any way related to these other users.
The buyers should have their own login which is different from the users. 
I have come across many questions with answers about different login but they are not really what i need.
I also do not intend to change my schema. 
My questions:
1. Is it possible to use two controllers in this case the buyers and users controller for my aunthentication?
2. How can buyers log in with an e-mail and password that is in the buyers table and for the application to authenticate them?
3. How do i add these buyers to my application without adding a new group for them?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the login is using the cake auth component. So if you make a model for your buyers you can verify if their authentication is valid and if it is, use the auth component to log the buyer.

Look at my answer there :
[cakephp auth component, use two models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11834646/cakephp-auth-component-use-two-models/11834761#11834761)

Comment: Im getting this error after i attempt to log in with the buyers or any user in the users table, don't know if you know anything about it

Authentication adapter &quot;ModelOne&quot; was not found.

Comment: I can not see what is the error right away like that, but it looks like you wrote a wrong model name somewhere. The other possibility would be that you did not defined the model used in the auth component and therefore, since he can't find one he returns you an error. Do you have the trace of that error or any more info? Go look at error.log in app/tmp/logs